# Is it JSON arrays? 

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, arrays

```
json_arr = "{"name" : "John","class":"09"},{"name":"Miley","class":"10"}"
```

Is this a valid JSON array? Is it arrays of arrays in JSON? I am new to this and a little confused. If it is right how can I loop through this array and parse each json array? Thank you!

I wrote this :

```
require 'json'
json_arr.each do |x|
pa = JSON(x)
end
```

When I printed pa, it was not parsed.

Comment: The very first line of your code is not a valid Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to surround your array with `[]`:

```
json_arr = '[{"name" : "John","class":"09"},{"name":"Miley","class":"10"}]'
```

In order to loop through the array, you have to *parse* the JSON string:

```
arr = JSON.parse(json_arr)
# => [{"name"=>"John", "class"=>"09"}, {"name"=>"Miley", "class"=>"10"}]
arr.each do |x|
  # do something with x
end
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not a valid array, JSON arrays are surrounded by []. Besides, you're using unescaped double quotes inside double quotes.

Something close to a valid array will look like this:

`[{"name":"john", "class":"09"},{"name":"Miley","class":"10"}]`

Answer (score 1):

Check your json array on this site http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in json follow this syntax `[item1, item2, item3]` so you are missing the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

In short: No, it's not valid. This is what you're looking for:

```
[
        {
                "name" : "John",
                "class" : "09"
        },
        {
                "name" : "Miley",
                "class" : "10"
        }
]
```

To test this in the future, [try this tool](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).